# Exit remote desktop and return session to console

Tags: windows, session, dns, console, administrator

I am trying to execute tscon from console for a user that is not administrator and I get an error. If I try to execute tscon for the same user as an administrator I get another access error. You may see attachment.

It might be useful to say that I know the username and password of both administrator and user and that they are both users on a domain. I also tried

```
%windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console /password:*
```

instead of

```
%windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
```

but it didn't work for the password that I have.

Do you know how and if I can execute this script without access errors?

[image: Screen shot of error]

Comment: `tscon` will work if run in local system context.  Try something like `psexec -s \\127.0.0.1 tscon ...` (you will of course need admin access)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks a lot. That did the job!